# Parallelismus in "... dem einen ... andere"

Tags: meaning, usage, article, parallelism

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*. Ein Leserbrief zum Thema selbstbestimmes Sterben.

> Sterben ist eine höchstpersönliche Angelegenheit: Was dem einen als würdelos scheint, kann für andere ein Lichtblick sein.

Die Konstruktion "... dem einen ... andere" schneint mir nicht parallel. Außerdem ist mir die Bedeutung nicht klar. Warum würde man **dem einen** mit dem Artikel spezifisch macht, **andere** aber nicht?

Ich würde eher sagen entweder

> (a) Was **dem einen** als würdelos scheint, kann für **die anderen** ein Lichtblick sein.

oder

> (b) Was **einem** als würdelos scheint, kann für **andere** ein Lichtblick sein.

Gibt es Gründe, warum der Ausgangssatz bevorzugt ist?

Comment: Warum muss es exakt parallel sein? Keiner sagt, dass man es nicht auch "fast parallel" machen kann. Reine Geschmackssache.

Comment: @dirkt Danke für Deinem Kommentar. Was ist denn mit der Bedeutung? Warum würde man **dem einen** mit dem Artikel spezifisch macht, **andere** aber nicht?

Comment: Warum sollte man es nicht tun? Vielleicht mag der Autor keine exakten Parallelismen, weil sie ihm stilitisch zu langweilig sind, deshalb bricht er sie auf und macht sie nur "fast" parallel. Wie gesagt, Geschmackssache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es liegt kein Parallelismus vor, sondern ein (attributiver) Nebensatz, der als Subjekt verwendet wird):

> **Was dem einen als würdelos scheint,** kann für andere ein Lichtblick sein.

Der Nebensatz ersetzt das von ihm beschriebene, "eigentliche" **Subjekt**.

> **Das**, was dem einen als würdelos scheint, kann für andere ein Lichtblick sein.

Anderes Beispiel:

> Wer das Leben nicht als Spiel betrachtet, hat schon verloren.

Comment: Danke. Wenn man stattdessen sagt "Was **einem** als würdelos scheint, ...", würde sich die Bedeutung überhaupt verändern?

Comment: @boaten Ja, **einem** hätte in diesem Fall die Funktion von *man* - wodurch die Aussage sinnlos würde, vergleichbar mit "Was man als sinnlos erachtet, kann für andere ein Lichtblick sein".